# Why does my render partial call not give me proper access to the local variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On my `Home#Index` page, I have this:

```
  <%= render 'home/popular_products', :collection => @products, :as => :product %>
```

In my `Home#_popular_products` view, I have this:

```
<div class="span2 recommended">
  <%= image_tag product.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
</div>
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:0x007f871c4f6848>:0x007f871cdb7e28>
```

As far as I understand it, I shouldn't even have to specify the `:as` attribute in my `render` statement - but I tried this to be explicit after just using the `:collection => @products` wouldn't work.

In my `Home#Index Controller` I have this:

```
@products = Product.all.sample(6)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to specify the `:partial` option if you want to pass in any other options. Ie:

```
<%= render :partial => 'home/popular_products', :collection => @products, :as => :product %>
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you put `_popular_products.html.erb` file in your `app/views/home/`? I think you're using partial not following convention of rails, so rails's not understood `product` variable. Your partial should be named `_product.html.erb` if you want to used like that. With that partial, you can write like this:

```
<%= render @products %>
```

**Update**

#### Solution 1

Index page:

```
<%= render 'popular_products', :collection => @products %>
```

Partial:

```
<%= image_tag popular_products.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

#### Solution 2

Index page:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= render :partial => "popular_products", :locals => { :product => product } %>
<% end %>
```

Partial:

```
<%= image_tag product.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

Comment: I don't neccessarily want to use `render @products`..I just want the partial to work. That's why I used the full call that provided the full path of the partial - i.e. `<%= render 'home/popular_products', :collection => @products, :as => :product %>`. Yes, it `_popular_products.html.erb` is in my `app/views/home/` As far as I understand it, shouldn't the instance variable specified in the `:collection` call already be initialized in the controller - which mine is. What am I missing?

Comment: Nope...that doesn't work. Still gives me the same error, except now it says `undefined local variable or method 'popular_product' for #<#<Class:0x007f871cf19640>:0x007f871cf16170>`

Comment: sorry, with solution 1, your variable should be `popular_products`

Comment: Nope... Andrew pointed out the issue I was having. I was missing the `:partial` option in my `render` call. Thanks for trying though.